# Best way to scan playframe code using sonarQube

Tags: playframework, sonarqube, sbt

I am new to sonarQube and want to understand the best approach to scan the play framework code, built using sbt. I want to learn the basics for e.g. Should we scan the source code or the class files, how to integrate it with play setup, even a reference/source to learn sonar would be quiet helpful. Could anyone suggest it?